# how to create tensorflow-lite model .bin for android NN api

Tags: android, neural-network

How to create the tensorflow lite model

presented in below link?

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/nn_sample/app/src/main/assets

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model following the documentation at: https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/devguide

For the NN-API example, you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t= tf.placeholder(name="t", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(2,1))
w=tf.constant([3.0,4.0])

temp=t+w
val=temp[0]*temp[1]

out = tf.identity(val, name="out")

with tf.Session() as sess:
   tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(sess.graph_def, [t], [out])
   open("converteds_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```